# cross ratio definition

Tags: projective-geometry, cross-ratio

I'm stuck with this exercise: I have 4 points  in the projective plane $\Bbb{P}^2(\Bbb{R})$

$$P_0=\{0,0,1\},\quad P_1=\{0,1,-1\},\quad P_2=\{1,-1,0\},\quad P_3=\{1,1,-3\}$$

and I have to compute their cross ratio, so I tried to see if they are collinear.
I used the theorem that say:

4 points $(P,Q,T,R)$ are collinear $\Leftarrow \Rightarrow$ $rg \begin{pmatrix}p_0&p_1&p_2\\t_0&t_1&t_2\\q_0&q_1&q_2\\r_0&r_1&r_2 \end{pmatrix}\le2$

but the rg of my matrix is $=3$. Am I doing something wrong? And, is the collinear's condition necessary?

Comment: They’re quite clearly not colinear since any point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ on the line $P_0P_2$ must have $x_1=-x_2$.

Comment: Cross-ratios are generally introduced as invariants of colinear points, but one can also compute the cross-ratio of four points on a common conic. Perhaps that’s what’s intended here.

Comment: But I don't understand, how can I do it on a common conic?

Comment: Is that all there is to the problem statement? There’s no other context? If not, then it is ill-posed. Even if the cross-ratio were relative to some common conic, there must be a specific conic for this computation.

Comment: I need to prove that exist a projective transformation between 2 sets of points ($(P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3)$ is one of them) and to prove this I have to show that the 2 cross-ratios are equals

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. The cross-ratio of a set of four arbitrary points isn’t even defined, so it can’t be projectively invariant. However, if you have concrete point correspondences, you can prove that a projectivity exists by just constructing it.

Comment: Which is the source of this exercise? Which is the **complete setting** for it? The *cross ratio* is a strong projective invariant, but it is restricted to some specific projective setting (line, affine plane, conic, cubic, ...) As @amd also mentioned, the present data is not sufficient. The exercise is usually given (in a book, in a course) in a concrete setting, which is this? Please give (full) references.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't need to check if they were collinear. They were in general position (and the other 4 points also were in general position), so (after multiplying the coordinates by some constants) you had two projective frames. The fundamental points of these two projective frames are the projectivization of two bases of $\Bbb{R}^3$. We have a theorem that states that $f$ exists and its associated isomorphism is the one you find when you change the coordinates between the two bases.

(Plus the cross ratio (as far as we know) only works in $\Bbb{P}^1$)